# Weird issue with ruby version on mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to create a rails app and fails like so:

```
$ rails new blog

    Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5.0 or newer.

    You're running:
      ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

    Please upgrade to Ruby 2.5.0 or newer to continue.
```

However, my ruby version is 2.6.3 according to my system:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]

$ which ruby
/Users/flaab/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Rbenv has 2.6.5 activated.

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.6.5 (set by /Users/flaab/.ruby-version)
  mruby-dev
```

But it recognizes the wrong one as well.

```
$ which -a ruby
/Users/flaab/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

My gem env is...

```
flaab@MBP-de-Arturo ~ $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/flaab/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/flaab/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/flaab/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/flaab/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/flaab/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/flaab/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/flaab/.gem
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "echo \"gem" => "--no-document\" > ~/.gemrc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/flaab/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin
     - /opt/local/libexec/rbenv
     - /Users/flaab/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/flaab/bin
     - /Users/flaab/.rbenv/shims
     - /sw/bin
     - /Users/flaab/.local/lib/npm/bin
     - /Users/flaab/.composer/vendor/bin
```

How can I instruct gem to use the 2.6.5 version of ruby mentioned above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the output of `gem env` ?  Also, are you in an empty directory when you run `rails new` ?

Comment: Done, please check. Result is the same in empty or not empty directory. =(

Comment: well you have duplicate `/usr/local/bin` so that could be part of the problem.  Many problems can happen with rbenv when your PATH variable is not configured correctly.  Have you modified it in any of your shell load scripts?  What shell are you using?

Comment: I am on a mac using bash. Somehow the bash $PATH is fine but gem concatenates it twice. On gem, the path is twice the $path, concatenated.

Comment: Did this ever work?  Do you have many other ruby or rails projects using different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To no avail. Ditched mac and went back to developing on debian. No issues.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall using howebrew, follow this steps:

-Install homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

-Install with homebrew your ruby version:

```
brew install ruby@2.6
```

-Set 2.6 as default version:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.6/bin:$PATH"
```

-Restart your sheel and run the following command depending on the shell you have:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

-Verify it works with:

```
ruby -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Either run `rbenv global 2.5.0` to set your global ruby or create a `.ruby-version` file in the app directory to instruct rbenv to use a specific version.

`echo "2.5.0" >> .ruby-version` and then try again.

[Documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version)

Comment: Many thanks for myour help. Still fails. The wrong ruby binary is invoked =(

Comment: Change out the directory and then back in again. Also, make sure you are using `bin/rails` or `bundle exec rails` for good practice.

Comment: I also put the wrong versions in my code example, obviously make sure you update those number to your specifics

Comment: Yes, versions are correctly.  Yet the other one is invoked. 
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.6.5 (set by /Users/flaab/.ruby-version)
  mruby-dev

Comment: Try rbenv rehash

Comment: Thanks but still does not work. And /usr/bin/ruby belongs to macosx and I can't delete it, not even as root. LOL

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the current rails gem was installed under system Ruby. Try uninstalling it completely or doing gem install rails

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this already added to your `.bash_profile` ?

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

If not add the above lines to the bottom of the file, then close and restart your terminal(s).

It looks like your `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` may not be set correctly. Try the following command:

```
rbenv shell 2.6.5
```

Also, make sure you're in a new empty directory and do

```
rbenv local 2.6.5
```

Then try rails command again

```
rails new blog
```

Comment: Thank you. I do have the path in my bashrc (not profile). Still does not work properly ^^